# Which GCP service to choose for hosting Docker image stored at Container Registry?

Tags: docker, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-kubernetes-engine

I have a SPA app dockerized with single Dockerfile (server side is by Kotlin with Spring boot, front end is by typescript with React) and am trying to host that docker image on GCP as web app.

At first I thought Cloud Run cloud be appropriate, but it seems that Cloud Run is serverless service and not for hosting a web app. I understand there are several options; App Engine(flexible environment), Compute Engine and Kubernetes Engine.

Considering the story above, can I ask GCP community support to decide which one to choose for the purposes;

- Hosting Docker Image stored at Cloud Registry
- That app should be publicly deployed; .i.e. everyone can access that app via browser like every other web sites
- That deployed Docker Image needs to connect Cloud SQL to persist its data
- Planning to use Cloud Build for CI/CD environment

Any help would be very appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

IMO, you need to avoid what you propose (Kubernetes, Compute Engine and App Engine Flex) and to (re)consider Cloud Run and App Engine Standard.

If you have a container, App Engine Standard isn't compliant, but you can simply deploy your code and let App Engine standard building and deploying its own container (with your code inside).

My preference is Cloud Run, and it's perfectly designed for webapp, as long as:

- You only perform processing on request (no background process, not long running operation (more than 60 minutes))
- You don't need to store data locally (but to store data in external service, in databases or storage)

I also recommend you to split your front end and your backend.

- Deploy your Front End on App Engine standard or on Cloud Storage
- Deploy your backend in Cloud Run (and thus in a container)
- Put a HTTPS load balancer in front of both to remove CORS issues and to have only 1 URL to expose (behind your own domain name)

The main advantage are:

- If you serve your file from Cloud Storage you can leverage cache and thus to reduce the cost and the latency. Same thing if you use CDN capacity in load balancer. If you host your front end in Cloud Run or any other compute system, you will use CPU to only serve static file, and you will pay for this CPU/memory -> useless
- Separate the frontend and the backend let you the capacity to evolve independently the both part without redeploy the whole application, only the part that have changed.
- The proposed pattern is an entreprise grade pattern. starting from 16$ per month, you can scale high and globally. You can also activate a WAF on load balancer to increase the security and attacks prevention.

---

So now, if you are agree with that, what's your next questions?

Comment: Thank you so much for your expertise! I basically agree with your opinion, but still one thing to consider. 
When I split my back end and front end separately, is it possible to build CD environment (though I understand you have mentioned this redeploy in your answer)? 
Now what I need to do is just build CD env triggered  by merge action on GitHub. So I’m assuming I will just need to build two CD env; one is for back end with Cloud Run and the other is for front end with Cloud Storage?

Comment: If you have a mono repos for your front and your back, you can choose: either 1 build with all the step for the front and the back, and you run only the side that you want according to the file changes. Or build 2 pipeline, triggered on the same event. If it's backend file that changed, the pipeline continue and the frontend pipeline stop gracefully (nothing to do), or vice versa. The second solution is easier to maintain, especially the pipeline definition when you have a team front and a team back in your organization. But it's still matter of opinion!

Comment: Sorry for lacking my knowledge but can I confirm what the first part is describing? You wrote “1 build with all the step for the front and the back, and you run only the side that you want according to the file changes”. So does that mean “any push to mono repo triggers CI/CD process and Cloud Build will pick which service (Cloud Run for back or Cloud Storage for front) to deploy the built content as CD process”?

Comment: Yes, according to the directory updated (for example, the front dir or the back dir) the process will be different. If fact you can't run conditional step on Cloud Build, you run all steps. Thus, you need to add a condition at the beginning of each step and say "if it's for the back, continue, else exit the step gracefully and go to the next one)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I will try in the way you kindly introduced.